# Error creating Managed Zone: Error 400: Please verify ownership

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I try to migrate a dns zone from my old provider to the google cloud dns without luck.

The idea is to create the managed zone, add all needed dns records and then set the NS records for the domain at the old provider to the google cloud nameservers. This works for me in 99% of all cases.

But I am not able to create the managed zone in google cloud dns.

I get the following error message:

"Error creating ManagedZone: googleapi: Error 400: Please verify ownership of the domain (or a parent) at http://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/ and try again, verifyManagedZoneDnsNameOwnership“

I would like to verify the ownership via TXT record, but that is not possible without the zone.

Does anyone run into this problem before and has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can create a text record at the registra where you bought your domain. You just need to use their default ns records.

If it is already validated and you’re still running into issues then you can add the email of the service account that you’re creating the dns zone with as a valid account on the validation page.

That solved it for me.

I wrote a small blog on the steps you can take to solve it [here](https://blog.scottwalker.dev/posts/solving-dns-zone-validation-in-gcp/)